# How to get list of all people who change specific file in svn?

Tags: svn, blame

I have got project in some repo using svn. There are a lot of files and people, who changing this files. By "svn blame" I can see who change the specific file, but I don't know how to get a list of all people who change this file.
To sum up I would like to get list of all people who change specific file using svn. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
svn log --limit 999999 path_to_file
```

show all changes for file, so you can extract names and get unique only.

Answer (score 0):

```
svn log $filepath --xml | sed 's@</author>@\n</author>@' | xmllint --xpath '/log/logentry/author/text()' - | sort -u
```

will list all unique committers to `$filepath`.

If you want to sort committer by decreasing number of commits, just use:

```
svn log $filepath --xml | sed 's@</author>@\n</author>@' | xmllint --xpath '/log/logentry/author/text()' - | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```